# new ajax request on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have three tables and I'm displaying each one of them using a select list element and have ajax and jquery to return the tables. I want whenever I choose a new table from the list ajax should bring me data only from that table.

Here is my form:

```
<div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">Term</span>
                            <!-- I passed the tables name as values for a specific period -->
                            <select name="term" class="form-control" id="term">
                                <option value="">Select Period</option>
                                <option value="period_one">1st Period</option>
                                <option value="period_two">2nd Period</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Student Name</th>
                                <th>Subject</th>
                                <th>Class</th>
                                <th>Score</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="periodTable">

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The problem is not that I'm not getting the desired result. I'm getting the result that I want that's why I feel that there's no need for me to add codes from findGrades.php.

here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#term').on('change', function() {
  /* Act on the event */
    var term = $('#term').val();

    if (term != '') {
      $.ajax({
        url:"findGrades.php",
        type:"post",
        data:{"term":term},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            // Lfrankie solution
            $("#periodTable").replaceWith('<tbody id="periodTable"></tbody>');

           for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
                var htmlData = '<tr><td data-type="text" data-name="student_name" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="student_name">'+data[count].first_name+' '+data[count].middle_name+' '+data[count].surname+'</td>';

                htmlData += '<td data-type="text" data-name="subject_name" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="subject_name">'+data[count].subject_name+'</td>';

                htmlData += '<td data-type="text" data-name="class_name" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="class_name">'+data[count].class_name+'</td>';

                if (data[count].score <= 69 ) {
                    htmlData += '<td style="color:red;" data-type="text" data-name="score" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="score">'+data[count].score+'</td></tr>';
                } else {
                    htmlData += '<td data-type="text" data-name="score" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="score">'+data[count].score+'</td></tr>';
                }

               //I feel this is where my problem lies
               $("#periodTable").append(htmlData);

            }
            $('#dataTable').DataTable();
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#periodTable").html('');

    }

 });
});
```

The problem I'm having is whenever I select a table it brings the result fine, but when I select a new table it adds the new result to the old result.

Ex: table 1:

1. cat
2. rat

table 2
 1. cat
 2. rat
 3. dog
 3. goat

Whereas result 2 should only show 'dog' and 'goat'. I realize it's because of the way I'm adding data **$("#periodTable").append(htmlData);**. I have tried changing it to this **$("#periodTable").html(htmlData);** which only returns a single item from a table like 'cat' from table 1 and 'rat' from table 2

How can I effectively get this working. Let me know if more information is needed.

**Update:** Just added my html as requested by some. Also I included a essential aspect I forget to mention 'Datables', which I added also.

Comment: You should empty your table before re-populate it each time.

Comment: how can I accomplish that?

Comment: You need to empty before the loop and append IN the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the *HTML* for your page, I can only guess that you start with an empty table.  Your first AJAX call appends the first set of data.  Your second call *appends* its data, because that's what you've asked it to do.

To fix this, you have to **replace the empty table** at the start of your `success()` function.  You can then safely append the new data, whether it's the first time you call it or the *n*-th time.

Comment: what should I replace the empty table with and how do I best do it?

Comment: Since you didn't post your HTML, I'm _guessing_ you have something like `<table id="periodTable"></table>` in your original page code.  At the top of your `success()` function, before the `for` loop, add `$("#periodTable").replaceWith("<table id="periodTable"></table>");` to reset it.  (Note that you need to use both single and double quotes because you are nesting them.)

Comment: I tried to fix the text, but SO wouldn't let me (comments can only be edited for 5 minutes).  The correct code with correct quotes is `$("#periodTable").replaceWith('<table id="periodTable"></table>');`

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you're are telling me to do, but I've updated my code to show my html. Sorry for the headache.

Comment: based on what you recently suggested I got it working, but now having a slight problem with datatables. Have updated my code to match what you just suggested

Comment: BTW, after experimenting, I see that `$("#periodTable").replaceWith('<table id="periodTable"></table>');` and `$("#periodTable").html("")` are functionally equivalent for an otherwise empty table:  the first code replaces the "periodTable" element completely, the second replaces its _contents_ with an empty string, effectively removing all of the rows it contains.  In your case (now that I see the code), where "periodTable" is the `<tbody>` rather than the `<table>` you want to use the second method.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable `htmlData` before for loop and write  `$("#periodTable").html(htmlData);` after for loop.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#term').on('change', function() {
          /* Act on the event */
            var term = $('#term').val();

            if (term != '') {
              $.ajax({
                url:"findGrades.php",
                type:"post",
                data:{"term":term},
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data){
                   var htmlData="";
                   for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
                        htmlData += '<tr><td data-type="text" data-name="student_name" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="student_name">'+data[count].first_name+' '+data[count].middle_name+' '+data[count].surname+'</td>';

                        htmlData += '<td data-type="text" data-name="subject_name" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="subject_name">'+data[count].subject_name+'</td>';

                        htmlData += '<td data-type="text" data-name="class_name" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="class_name">'+data[count].class_name+'</td>';

                        if (data[count].score <= 69 ) {
                            htmlData += '<td style="color:red;" data-type="text" data-name="score" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="score">'+data[count].score+'</td></tr>';
                        } else {
                            htmlData += '<td data-type="text" data-name="score" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="score">'+data[count].score+'</td></tr>';
                        }



                    }

                       $("#periodTable").html(htmlData);
                }
              });
            } else {
              $("#periodTable").html('');

            }

         });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simply clear the html of `$("#periodTable")` before to populate it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#term').on('change', function() {
  /* Act on the event */
    var term = $('#term').val();

    //---> HERE BLANK THE periodTable <--- 
    $("#periodTable").html("");

    if (term != '') {
      $.ajax({
        url:"findGrades.php",
        type:"post",
        data:{"term":term},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
           for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
                var htmlData = '<tr><td data-type="text" data-name="student_name" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="student_name">'+data[count].first_name+' '+data[count].middle_name+' '+data[count].surname+'</td>';

                htmlData += '<td data-type="text" data-name="subject_name" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="subject_name">'+data[count].subject_name+'</td>';

                htmlData += '<td data-type="text" data-name="class_name" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="class_name">'+data[count].class_name+'</td>';

                if (data[count].score <= 69 ) {
                    htmlData += '<td style="color:red;" data-type="text" data-name="score" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="score">'+data[count].score+'</td></tr>';
                } else {
                    htmlData += '<td data-type="text" data-name="score" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="score">'+data[count].score+'</td></tr>';
                }

               //I feel this is where my problem lies
               $("#periodTable").append(htmlData);

            }
        }
      });
    } /* ELSE COULD BE REMOVED
      else {
      $("#periodTable").html('');

    }*/

 });
});
```

Comment: No, you should left `$("#periodTable").append(htmlData);` and add `$("#periodTable").html("");` before the ajax call.