# DataTables loading wrong results on ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have three tables and I'm displaying each one of them using a select list element and have ajax and jquery to return the tables. I want whenever I choose a new table from the list ajax should bring me data only from that table.

Here is my form:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon">Term</span>
                <!-- I passed the tables name as values for a specific period -->
                <select name="term" class="form-control" id="term">
                   <option value="">Select Period</option>
                   <option value="period_one">1st Period</option>
                   <option value="period_two">2nd Period</option>
                </select>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable">
              <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Student Name</th>
                        <th>Subject</th>
                        <th>Class</th>
                        <th>Score</th>
                   </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="periodTable">
              </tbody>
          </table>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Ajax is bring the results as expected, but the dataTables plugin I added is kind of not refreshing on the ajax calls. for example if I select '1st Period' and it returns the table of '1st Period' which has two(2) rows 'dog and cat'. dataTables tells me **Showing 1 to 10 of 2 entries** which is correct. But if I select '2nd Period' ajax returns the desire result but dataTables still shows **Showing 1 to 10 of 2 entries** even if '2nd Period' has less or more.

Also if a search is done on the next table it doesn't work as expected. Here is how I wrote my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#term').on('change', function() {
    var term = $('#term').val();
    if (term != '') {
      $.ajax({
        url:"findGrades.php",
        type:"post",
        data:{"term":term},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
           // clearing the table so that only result from the next table are shown. To do this I got help from this thread: 
           //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206680/new-ajax-request-on-drop-down-selection

           $("#periodTable").replaceWith('<tbody id="periodTable"></tbody>');
           for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
                var htmlData = '<tr><td data-type="text" data-name="student_name" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="student_name">'+data[count].first_name+' '+data[count].middle_name+' '+data[count].surname+'</td>';

                htmlData += '<td data-type="text" data-name="subject_name" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="subject_name">'+data[count].subject_name+'</td>';

                htmlData += '<td data-type="text" data-name="class_name" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="class_name">'+data[count].class_name+'</td>';

                if (data[count].score <= 69 ) {
                    htmlData += '<td style="color:red;" data-type="text" data-name="score" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="score">'+data[count].score+'</td></tr>';
                } else {
                    htmlData += '<td data-type="text" data-name="score" data-pk="'+data[count].id+'" class="score">'+data[count].score+'</td></tr>';
                }
                 $("#periodTable").append(htmlData);
            }
             // calling the data table function after data have been return by ajax  
             $('#dataTable').DataTable();

        }

      });
    } else {
        $('#periodTable').html('');
    }

 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use add rows not append html like this:
https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Comment: I'm looking at it but can't figure out how to do it, as I'm not adding rows when a button is click. Will appreciate a bit practical example.

Comment: when you click you append html to table, the new versions of jquery datatable not accept this way so you have to add rows to main table

Comment: I'm sorry I cant figure out how to do this. I have tried this: var try = $('#periodTable').DataTable(), and also added this: t.row.add( [
            data[count]).draw( false ). But to no avail. Is there a way that I can really do this?

Comment: try.row.add( [ data[count]).draw( false ).